# Play button won't work

Tags: actionscript-3, preloader

Sounds simple right? Apparently not, because what has worked countless times before for me won't work now, and I have no idea why, I have tried everything. This is for a preloader for as3.

```
stop();
this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loading);

function loading(e:Event):void {
    var total:Number = this.stage.loaderInfo.bytesTotal;
    var loaded:Number = this.stage.loaderInfo.bytesLoaded;

    preloader.bar_mc.gotoAndPlay(Math.floor((loaded/total)*100));

    if (total == loaded) {
        this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loading);
        preloader.playLoad.gotoAndPlay(2);
    }
}

preloader.playLoad.playButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playClick);

function playClick(ev:MouseEvent):void {
    gotoAndPlay(2);
}
```

Comment: may be some cross-domain restriction?

Comment: I don't know what that means, probably not, doesn't' sound like it has anything to do with my file. The only problem here is that the play button won't work, it would "gotoAndPlay(2);"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sound like playButton didn't catch that event.
try

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playClick);
```

and

```
function playClick(e:MouseEvent):void {

    trace(e.target)

    if(e.target == preloader.playLoad.playButton)
    {
        gotoAndPlay(2)
    }
}
```

and look what trace will throw, hope it helps